# nginx rewrite subfolder and file extension from the url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

This is my scenario

https://x.com/remove/something/subfolder/sub.html

should be rewritten to

https://x.com/something/subfolder/sub

i.e I want to remove a URL part (`remove` in this case) and the file extension `.html`

so far I've come with this

```
location /remove {
 rewrite ^/remove(/.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

but it's not working

UPDATE

got `remove` part solved by 
`rewrite ^/remove/(.*)$ https://x.com/$1 last;`

now just need the file extension removal only

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is capturing everything after the `/remove` part. You need to take the suffix out of the capture.

```
rewrite ^/remove(/.*)\.html$ $1 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details. Also, note use of the appropriate flag.